# How can I automatically organize data from a text file in a spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a text file like this:

[image: raw data]

and I would like to organize into Excel like this:

[image: excel data]

I could do this by hand manually for two data entries, but I would like to be able to automate this for a larger scale. What I've tried so far is to input the data into Excel using its built-in feature, but that's where I'm stuck. I tried to transpose the columns into rows, but that doesn't neatly organize it like I want it. Do I need to do some coding or is there a built-in function? If I do need coding, could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you used macros?  They are written in VBA "Visual Basic for Applications"  You would need a for loop and break on the text "Customer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try the Power Query Add-In for this. It has powerful commands for manipulating data.  There are functions underneath, but you can achieve a lot by just clicking the buttons in the Power Query window.  Working visually in Power Query is usually much easier than coding in VBA.

I had a go at this particular challenge and got it working.  You can download and use my demo file from my OneDrive:

http://1drv.ms/1AzPAZp

It's the file: Power Query demo - reorganising rows into columns.xlsx

As described on the ReadMe sheet, I only had to write one simple function - the rest was just clicking around the UI.  Power Query is great!

To use it against your own text files, just Edit the first Step in the Query to point to your file.  BTW you can even get Power Query to loop over the files in a folder if required.

Comment: Rewrote my answer after finding an easy way using Power Query.

Comment: This is fantastic and exactly what I needed! After fiddling around with it some more, I managed to work it for my needs. It was very intuitive! Thanks for introducing me to this powerful tool!

If there is a place that you recommend tor beginners for mastering Power Query, please let me know! Otherwise, thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome - it was a good training / brain exercise for me.  There's not a lot of PQ training around - probably the best way to start are the session recordings from recent Microsoft conferences e.g. https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2014?sort=sequential&direction=desc&term=power+query#fbid=

Answer (score 0):

Powershell in a dirty way.

```
$xlsFile="c:\temp\your.xlsx"
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$excel.displayAlerts = $false
$wbs=$excel.workbooks.open($xlsFile)
$ws=$wbs.sheets.item(1)
$ws.cells.item(1,1) = "Customer"
$ws.cells.item(1,2) = "Apples"
$ws.cells.item(1,3) = "Bananas"
$ws.cells.item(1,4) = "Oranges"
$row = 1
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("c:\temp\your.txt")
try {
    while ($true) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        if ($line.length -lt 3) {continue}
        switch ($line.substring(0,3))
            {
                "Cus" {
                    $val="'"+$line.split("#:")[1]
                    $row++
                    $ws.cells.item($row,1) = $val
                }
                "App" {
                    $val=$line.split(" ")[1]
                    $ws.cells.item($row,2) = $val
                }
                "Ban" {
                    $val=$line.split(" ")[1]
                    $ws.cells.item($row,3) = $val              
                }
                "Ora" {
                    $val=$line.split(" ")[1]
                    $ws.cells.item($row,4) = $val
                }
            }
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
}
$wbs.saveas($xlsFile)
$wbs.close()
$excel.quit()
$ws = $null
$wbs = $null
$excel = $null
```